# Change input type of keyboard android

Tags: android

Is there any way to dynamically change the soft input keyboard type? Like there is a button in the keypad by which we can switch between numeric or alpha keyboard. Can I provide the function programaticaly?  What I want to do is to show the number keyboard when user clicks an edit text, and then goes to normal keyboard if he press space.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try that but you can try setting the inputType of the editText to number, and set a text chage listener, that will wait for space. when it gets a space it changes the input type to text. [read here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html)

Comment: I tried, but the problem is, in the number keypad, the button is missing which allows us to go back to text mode